# Array type of intersection type of two objects

Tags: typescript

It is needed to intersect an object in typescript and then represent it as an array. Here is the [tutorial about the intersection of types in typescript](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/use-intersection-types-to-combine-types-in-typescript). What I want is also to make an array of it. For example if we have these two types:

```js
type User = {
    Name:string
}
```

I would like to add one more type for specific calls. ex:

```js
const registeredUser:User & {RegistrationDate:Date}
```

This means that the `registeredUser` could contain `RegistrationDate` as well as `Name`.

How to make an **array** of that type, I couldn't come up with the right solution. The wrong one is here:

```js
const registeredUser:User & {RegistrationDate:Date}[]
```

I'd like to be able to declare `registeredUser` as an empty array of intersected objects and then fill it by need.

Comment: `(User & {RegistrationDate:Date})[]`

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is the answer.